# How does this mod_rewrite code resolve properly?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

It works, but I'm wondering how it works. For example, if I type in `example.com/main`, I get the file at `www.example.com/main.php`. How do I get the `.php` extension if the code tells the rewriting to stop after adding the `www.` to the beginning of `example.com`?

**Edit:** Or should I create a unique ID only for the purpose of logging in the remembered user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The particular behavior you're asking about comes about because the rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

is a 301 redirect; it instructs the browser to initiate a completely new HTTP request.  The `L` only causes (can only cause) it to be the last rule executed for *that request*; the new request comes in with the correct hostname and proceeds onward.